# Can't one read responses from curl handles without having to use temporary files to write responses received?

Tags: curl, response

(Refer http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)
Using the C libcurl requires you to set the curl option CURLOPT_WRITEDATA passing in a FILE*. Or else it will simply output the response received to stdout. Seems one is then forced to use temporary files just for reading responses, and there is no way to read response directly into a memory buffer. It looks very sh!tty and very hard to believe. Php curl has better interfaces. Is this one should live with while using C libcurl? It gets messier still when using curl multi handles, as we have to use multiple temporary files then.
Please clarify before I shoot myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked and answered a millions times before. Here's an example how to do it:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

Comment: Helpful indeed, thanks. So they are reallocing buffer everytime it gets called for the same transfer. Will it make any difference if I use a string* and keep appending to the string, so that the reallocation happens automatically? I hope not. Relatedly, the first argument to the write callback function is void* and not char*. Any idea why? Can I safely typecast it to char* and make a string out of it?